# How to know the current visibility offset in TextEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

When you write in a TexBox/TexEdit, if the text is larger than the size of the control, it is scrolled to the right.

How can I get the current visibility offset or scrolled length?

To illustrate what I want:

[image]

The black box represent the full text. The red box is the TextEdit, containing the visible part of the text. The brown vertical line is the caret. What I want to know is the offset measure in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

I have done minimal testing on this, and it seems to work, though there are cases where it may be off by 1 pixel:

```
int offset = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0).X;
```

I have put this in the TextChanged event handler for testing purposes.

Let me know if it does what you need.

Cheers

EDIT: I have played with adding the width of the border (defaulted to Fixed3D) by doing this instead:

```
int offset = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0).X + SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width;
```

This seems to give better results.

Comment: Seems to work on a TextBox, thanks. Do you know how to do the same in a DevExpress TextEdit?